# AH00036: access to / failed apache

Tags: apache

I have mounted an S3 bucket using s3fs onto an Ec2 instance and have provided the path in the Document root of the httpd.conf file for apache. The S3 bucket has a multi folder hierarchy and the index.html file is present in the 5th hierarchy like "a/b/c/d/e". I have mounted the s3 bucket using the command below:

```
s3fs <bucket_name> /temp -o passwd_file=~/.passwd-s3fs -ouid=1001,gid=1001,allow_other,mp_umask=002
```

However, when I try to access the public IP of the instance, I get a 403 error. I have updated the document root and also have allowed the directory in the conf file.

```
DocumentRoot "/temp/Reports/2021/02/24/final-report"

<Directory "/temp/Reports/2021/02/24/final-report">
AllowOverride None
# Allow open access:
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

When I verified the error_log file, I notice an error as below:

```
Operation not permitted: [client 124.123.x.x:52039] AH00036: access to / failed (filesystem path '/temp/Reports/2021')
```

P.S: the ec2 instance and S3 bucket are in different accounts but I'm able to access the S3 contents from Ec2 instance.